Menu select value is the next menu select
I am trying to achieve this:

So you have a select options menu with labels and depending what you select a corresponding value shows.
This value, better said these values should be a next select options menu with labels. The values become labels then basically.
I can show the corresponding values to the selected labels from the first menu but how to make those values selectable labels in a second menu?
So basically:

My code:
import { SetStateAction, useState } from "react";

export default function Sort() {
  let selecciones = [
    {
      label: "Price",
      subsorter: [
        { sorter: "cheap to expensive" },
        { sorter: "expensive to cheap" },
        { sorter: "small to big" },
        { sorter: "big to small" }
      ],
    },
    { label: "Distance",
      subsorter: [
        { sorter: "close to far" },
        { sorter: "far to close" },
        { sorter: "beach nearby" },
        { sorter: "restaurant nearby" }
      ],
  },
    { label: "Reviews", colour: "lowest to highest" },
  ];
  let [selecciones, setSelecciones] = useState("Make a seleccion");
  let handleSeleccionChange = (e: {
    target: { value: SetStateAction<string> };
  }) => {
    setSeleccion(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex">
        <div className="">{seleccion}</div>
        <select
          onChange={handleSeleccionChange}>
          <option value="Make a seleccion">-- Filter -- </option>
          {selecciones.map((seleccion) => (
            <option key={seleccion.label} value={seleccion.sorter}>
              {seleccion.label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="flex">
        <div className="">{seleccion}</div>
        <select
          onChange={handleSeleccionChange}>
          <option value="Select a fruit">-- By -- </option>
          {selecciones.map((seleccion) => (
            <option key={seleccion.label} value={seleccion.sorter}>
              {seleccion.label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

I tried different things and settled in the end with a submenu underneath Price and Distance that needs to be selected (so everything in one menu instead of two). Not what I want sadly but I got stuck.

From my understanding of the problem i tried to show the selection of two dropdown values stored in seperate states or you can use single state using objects.


import React, { useState, ChangeEvent } from "react";

interface Subsorter {
  sorter: string;
}

interface Selection {
  label: string;
  subsorter?: Subsorter[];
}

const selecciones: Selection[] = [
  {
    label: "Price",
    subsorter: [
      { sorter: "cheap to expensive" },
      { sorter: "expensive to cheap" },
      { sorter: "small to big" },
      { sorter: "big to small" },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "Distance",
    subsorter: [
      { sorter: "close to far" },
      { sorter: "far to close" },
      { sorter: "beach nearby" },
      { sorter: "restaurant nearby" },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "Reviews",
    subsorter: [{ sorter: "lowest to highest" }],
  },
];

export default function Sort() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string>("Make a selection");
  const [subSelected, setSubSelected] = useState<string>("");

  const handleSelectionChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const selectedLabel = e.target.value;
    setSelected(selectedLabel);

    // Reset sub-selection when main selection changes
    setSubSelected("");
  };

  const handleSubSelectionChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setSubSelected(e.target.value);
  };

  // Filter the selected category to get the subsorter options
  const selectedCategory = selecciones.find(
    (category) => category.label === selected
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex">
        <div className="">{selected}</div>
        <select onChange={handleSelectionChange}>
          <option value="Make a selection">-- Filter --</option>
          {selecciones.map((seleccion) => (
            <option key={seleccion.label} value={seleccion.label}>
              {seleccion.label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      {selectedCategory && selectedCategory.subsorter && (
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="">{subSelected}</div>
          <select onChange={handleSubSelectionChange}>
            <option value="">-- By --</option>
            {selectedCategory.subsorter.map((sub) => (
              <option key={sub.sorter} value={sub.sorter}>
                {sub.sorter}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}



hope this helps.
